# QGIS SAGA Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, saga

I am using SAGA --> Grid Calculus --> Raster Calculator on QGIS version 2.6.  The formula I am using is:

```
ifelse(gt(a,0), (a), b)
```

where `a` is my layer with values in a greater extent than that of `b`.  The resulting layer doesn't seem to abide by the else condition of my formula contains only 0s.

Dug into error log and found a bunch of these type errors:

> ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin\gdalplugins\gdal_ECW_x

Comment: But even re-loading gdal_ECW didn't seem to fix the issue.  I am guessing this is a bug with this version of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can accomplish this task easily using GDAL via OSGeo4W Shell and the following GDAL:

```
gdal_calc -A inn1.tif -B inn2.tif --outfile=test.tif --calc="where(A>0,A,B)"
```